# Добавить тег blazor

Tags: предложение, метки, добавление-меток

Появился фреймворк blazor.
Уже пару раз хотел задать вопрос по этой части, но не существует такого тега. сам не могу добавить, так как не имею большой репутации, может ли кто-то это сделать или куда-то надо написать?

Comment: К каким вопросам добавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874034/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-js-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-blazor-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создал метку [blazor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor) с небольшим кратким описанием.